# The relation of LED and the sine voltage source

Tags: led

[image]

If i connect the LED with a sine voltage source,and if this voltage source generate a positive half wave for 0.5ms first,and then generate a negative half wave for 0.5ms.What will the LED happen?

1.light for 0.5ms first,and then dark for 0.5ms

2.dark for 0.5ms first,and then light for 0.5ms

3.light for almost 1ms,except when voltage is 0,which in the middle of two half wave

Comment: This sounds like homework

Comment: modeling the LED as a 100 ohm resistor seems like a recipe for disaster and indicative of a lack of understanding of the fundamentals

Comment: Homework. ----------------------

Comment: This is not the homework  ok?

Comment: @JorenVaes The LED image is light bulb originally,i just change its name,and i didn't notice  the ohms first.I just want to show the relation of LED  and the voltage source

Comment: No, not OK.  And, you show a incandescent bulb, but label it "LED".  Huh? What?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Depends on the voltage.
If the voltage is lower than +/- 20V, the diode will emitt the light and no damage will be done (because reverse voltage across LED is allowed under 20V).

The thing is, you can power supply also the LED with 230VAC, but you have to add a 1N4007 (which reverse voltage is up to 1000V) in series, just to make sure, it only glows in the 1st period of sine wave, while the other is turned off.

What's more important is, that there's about 10mA of current going through the LED, because it's the current type of an element (anything between 1mA and 20mA will do it). That's why, you should also use a resistor (not always, but in simple circuits like this) in series with the diode.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There is no way around it - it appears that you do not understand how LEDs should be used. All but complex LED arrays will be toast at 20 V. Perhaps you just have experience with big LED arrays made for direct-to-mains applications or such?

Comment: Just plain wrong.

Comment: No.
I was pointing out, that the LEDs are current elements, not voltage. If you put on a LED a 20V voltage and use a 1k8 resistor in series, it will glow just fine.
And what's incorrect here?

Comment: @Jakey but you didn't point that out, you just said "if the voltage is lower than +/- 20V" - no mention of any resistors untill the last paragraph. In addition, as long as you have a big enough resistor in front of it, you could have a LED+resitor connected to 1 GV (would be a pretty darn beefy resistor). 
You also don't point out that they are diodes, and thus will only pass current in one direction.

Comment: @Jakey So,you mean that if the voltage  is -20<Voltage<+20,the LED situation will be 3.light for almost 1ms,except when voltage is 0,which in the middle of two half wave?

Comment: I was referring to your first paragraph, after which I stopped reading.  It is just plain wrong.  20 V forwards will blow out any LED I've ever seen.  Most LEDs are only rated for 5 V reverse, so 20 V in reverse will likely cause damage.  20 V forward with a suitable resistor in series would be OK, but there is no mention of a resistor.  20 V in reverse could still damage many LEDs, whether a resistor is in series or not.

Comment: @JorenVaes: I admit, I could have write it better. That's for sure.
And no, the answer is NO to the question, related to 1 GV. You would also need another diode, which would have a reverse voltage >1GV (which I kindly believe, doesn't exist).
I assumed, that he (Charging boy) knows, that diodes pass current only in 1 direction.

Comment: @chargingboy: Not exactly. It will glow only, while the positive voltage will be applied to the positive terminal of the diode, which means, only 1/2 of the time.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: There was mention of a resistor, but as I've written it before, I could write that "answer" better and stated about resistor much earlier.

Comment: @Jakey why would I need another diode? I never clamed this was alternating voltage. Perhaps if you do use alternating voltage, you would need this second diode, but it would be much easier to put a low-voltage diode in anti-parallel. In forward conduction of the LED it will be reverse biased. The LED acts as a clamp, limiting the reverse voltage to a few volts. In reverse bias (with respect to the LED) the diode will become forward biased, and the resistors will limit the current, and by doing so again limit the voltage to a reasonable level.

Comment: @Jakey so you mean like the 1. light for 0.5ms first,and then dark for 0.5ms right?

Comment: @chargingboy: yes. But because the frequency is so high (1kHz), your eye will NOT notice it as blinking.

Comment: @Jakey That is a really good reply,better than the others